# How to use Moq to mock X509Certificate2?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mocking, moq

I need to have my X509Certificate2.Subject return gibberish for code coverage in unit tests. I've tried using Moq, but it fails because Subject is not a virtual method. Is there a way to do this, or do I have to re-invent the wheel here?

```
          Mock<X509Certificate2> mockCert = new Mock<X509Certificate2>(contextAccessor.Certificate.RawData);
      mockCert.Setup(m=>m.Subject).Returns("kjewnr,mwnzlxkcuvlkrj,wmelq");
      mockCert.CallBase = true;

      contextAccessor.Certificate = mockCert.Object;
      authenticatorAccessor.LogAuthentication(context);
```

Can Moq do this? If not, are there other libraries that will work for me? Thanks.

Comment: Error is: System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: m => m.Subject

Comment: For properties use [Stub or SetupProperty](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/Mock(T)/M/SetupProperty(TProperty)) rather than Setup

Comment: Have you seen the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836247/how-to-create-a-minimal-dummy-x509certificate2)? They mention something called Moles that may help you. Either that or creating a test certificate, because it seems that what you are attempting to do cannot be done, as the `Subject` property is non-virtual, as you say.

Comment: Stub doesn't exist in the mock framework, and setupProperty has the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but since I ran into this via Google, I figured I'd mention what worked for me.

```
private X509Certificate2 CreateSelfSignedCertificate()
{
    var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create();
    var req = new CertificateRequest("foobar", ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    X509Certificate2 cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5));

    return cert;
}
```

Where foobar is the subject you want mocked.

Answer (score 0):

It actually can't be done. I've moved away from Moq and am went back to using accessors instead.